# grid header is not moving with scroll bar

Tags: react-data-grid

I am using react-data-grid package for grid in `react.js`. To add search option to all columns, I used `react-data-grid-addons`.

Problem is that now the scroll bar is not working properly: grid header is not moving with the scroll bar.

Comment: Share the code with us.

Comment: It is same as react-data-grid-addons package. We have just added following css:
.react-grid-Viewport > div {
    max-height: 52vh !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    position: relative !important;
}
.react-grid-Viewport {
    top: -2px !important;
    position: relative !important;
}